# How to make debugger built process show an assertion dialog in case of "Detected memory leaks" CRT message?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, mfc

Visual Studio has a handy feature in CRT that displays something akin to the following message in the debugger output window if it detects memory leaks when the debuggee process exits:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{9611} normal block at 0x000000000269D0C0, 492 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

It is all very helpful, but I was wondering if there's a setting to throw an assertion dialog box when this happens?

Or if there's no such setting, is there a CRT function that can be called, say something like `bool WereAnyMemoryLeaksDetected();` that I can call from a `_DEBUG` build myself before my process exits?

Otherwise it's way too easy not to notice the exact moment when that message about memory leaks is shown for the first time.

Comment: [Memory Leak Detection Enabling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: You should visit this MS page for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx#BKMK_Check_for_heap_integrity_and_memory_leaks

There is no way to detect a memory leak while your program is still running, You could compare memory states while the application is running, but that is a very complex matter indeed.

Comment: @IInspectable: answered this question. If I call [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb(v=vs.90).aspx) right before my app closes, it will return non-zero if there were any CRT memory leaks detected. I can then throw an assertion. There's a problem displaying it with `MessageBox` though. But [I solved that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44599182/843732) too.

Comment: _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks  will report leaks for global objects.